# Using a Singleton for Current logged in user of mobile app

Tags: android, ios

Is creating a Singleton to keep track of the current logged in user of a mobile app a bad idea? The class below is something along the lines of what I've used before and it works fine, but I always feel it's not the best way of doing things.

```
public class LoggedInUser {

   private static LoggedInUser ourInstance = null;
   User user;

   public static LoggedInUser getInstance() {
        return ourInstance != null ? ourInstance : new LoggedInUser();
    }

    private LoggedInUser () {
        user = new User();
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }
}
```

I use the info of the user pretty often throughout the app, and sometimes the User object isn't trivially small so passing the object between each view doesn't sound like the best option either. What is normal practice for this? 
The user has to log in every time they use the app, so I also don't want to write the information to the phone necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a similar question ([Is Singleton the best way to keep data in memory on an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44884329/is-singleton-the-best-way-to-keep-data-in-memory-on-an-android-application)) and the answer posted by charlag is actually pretty mature:

> I would use the following: Interface CurrentUser. CurrentUser has methods to retrieve and update user. User may be stored in DB, preferences or mixed. I would use Dagger to inject CurrentUser when needed. CurrentUser implementation should itself be a singleton, because Dagger doesn't guarantee qualities of singleton. Bonus points if your CurrentUser has something like RxJava stream or LiveData to keep observers up-to-date.
>
> As an alternative to Singleton you may want to implement Fragment
> Holder pattern with retained fragments but in your situation Singleton
> seems better. Just make sure that you use interfaces and injection to
> not compromise testability and to keep your components separated.

Do not fall into keeping your objects within the App class, unless it is crucial to instantiate your app's dependencies correctly - it sounds nice and easy, but can also get out of control pretty quick.

Answer (score -1):

Singleton is normal.
But you can always use `Application` class and its variables (both static and object) to store the data.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

public static LoggedInUser user;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
       user = LoggedInUser.getInstance();

//...
}

//or even
public LoggedInUser user_obj;
    }
```

`AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:icon="@drawable/iconlite"
        android:label="@string/app_alias"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

somewhere in the code use `MyApp.user` or `((MyApp)getApplication()).user_obj`

Comment: In my opinion, storing objects like this in an Application class is the first step to bringing dirt into your code. The user class is not bound to the application class and this should not be the way to achieve your "scoping" problem.